# Best practice to initialize groupshared variable

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, initialization, hlsl, compute-shader

I am using a big groupshared variable to do my computations on, but recently I found (the hard way) out that groupshared memory is not initialized.
For my use-case I need it to be initialized since I will be copying it back directly to a texture after all the computations.

So I ask what the better methods are to go about this? Mainly performance-wise, because I imagine that the initialization has to happen as part of the whole shader program.

This is how I am currently handling it, but it doesn't seem to be working as intended because some data still persists in the next dispatch. Basically each thread gets assigned a number of values to initialize, then afterwards wait for the other threads.

```
#define GroupSize 64
#define FoWMap_Size 4096
groupshared uint _FoWMap[FoWMap_Size];

[numthreads(GroupSize, 1, 1)]
void FOWMapGenerator(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    uint instPerThread = FoWMap_Size / GroupSize;

    [unroll]
    for (uint k = 0; k < instPerThread; k++)
    {
        uint realID = (id.x * instPerThread) + k;
        if (realID > FoWMap_Size)
            break;
        
        _FoWMap[realID] = 0;
    }

//wait for all units to finish
GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync();

...
...
...
}
```

This was my quick and sloppy method beforehand:

```
void InitArray(uint size)
{
    for (uint i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        _FoWMap[i] = 0;
    }
}

[numthreads(GroupSize, 1, 1)]
void FOWMapGenerator(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    InitArray(FoWMap_Size);

...
...
...
}
```

However I scrapped this one because in theory it would mean that every thread is completely initializing the groupshared array, which isn't ideal performance-wise.
It's possible that the compiler is optimizing this away for me, but I am not sure.

So all-in-all, how do you go about initializing groupshared arrays? I am in desperate need for advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `SV_GroupThreadID`, the local thread ID inside a group, instead of `SV_DispatchThreadID`, the global thread ID across groups, when initializing groupshared memory in your case.

Otherwise you'll be going out of bound for your array index in your second group and up.